# How can I log into a windows domain with a usb key

Tags: usb-flash-drive, login, active-directory

I would like to log into a windows domain (active directory) with a USB key without having to install a client on every workstation.

My use case is for Elementary School kids who have issues typing in their user name and password.

I would like to have it so that inserting a usb key completes the login process automatically, however traditional user/pass entry is still available.

Comment: What sort of authentication are you going to us exactly?

Comment: Assuming Windows clients: Windows does not support this inherently, you will need to install something on all the client machines. If you are determined to do it without installing anything, this is unanswerable.  If you are willing then there's lots of info/solutions out there (available via a quick web search) for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable smart card login and then use this:
http://www.mysmartlogon.com/products/eidvirtual.html

Comment: This still requires entry of a PIN, right?